# Which is the proper way to mark transient?

Tags: java, serialization, transient

If there are several references in different classes (*that are pitfallOne, pitfallTwo and pitfallThree in the following example*) to the same object is it enough to mark only one of them as `transient` to prevent that object's serialization (considering that those classes are to be serialized)? If not, which should be marked as `transient`?

I'm not sure if class structure matters here so let it be like this:

```
class Zero {
    ...
}

class One {
    ...
    Zero pitfallOne = new Zero();
}

class Two {
    ...
    One instOne = new One();
    transient Zero pitfallTwo = instOne.pifallOne;
}

class Three {
    ...
    Two instTwo = new Two();
    Zero pitfallThree = instTwo.pifallTwo;
}
```

Comment: You can only mark fields which are references as transient, not objects. If you want to prevent an object being serialized you have to mark every field which might point to it as transient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transient marking is attached to a field of a class, and not to an object. Since you have a new field in each class it should be marked as transient.